# start WebLogic from Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, weblogic, nohup

I want to stop and start WebLogic from Jenkins. If I start by shell script in Jenkins:

```
./startWebLogic.sh
```

the process is not finished, but WebLogic is started.

If I start by shell script with nohup in Jenkins:

```
. ./setWLSEnv.sh

nohup ./startWebLogic.sh > /dev/null &
```

the process is finished, but WebLogic is not started.

I tried the same script on the same server from putty, in result process is finished and WebLogic is started.

How I can start WebLogic and execute other shell script from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. But this code has one issue. When you put your process in background you can't see logs of the process. And if your weblogic couldn't start at all you will know that only on the further stages (trying to deploy - in my case).

```
stage('Start WLS') {
    steps {
        sh '${DOMAIN_BIN_DIR}/startWebLogic.sh &'
    }
}
```

Hope, someone will give a better solution with ability to determine the fact of Weblogic's fall on the running stage.